# How to fix Requirement already satisfied issue (pip install)?

Tags: linux, pip

I'm trying to install sceptre with the command pip install sceptre. But I get the output below.

```
Requirement already satisfied: sceptre in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2<3,>=2.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sceptre) (2.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYaml<6.0,>=5.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sceptre) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx<3,>=2.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sceptre) (2.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click<8.0,>=7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sceptre) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: boto3<2.0,>=1.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sceptre) (1.17.67)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama>=0.3.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sceptre) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2.0.0,>=1.11.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sceptre) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging<17.0,>=16.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sceptre) (16.8)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from boto3<2.0,>=1.3->sceptre) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: botocore<1.21.0,>=1.20.67 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from boto3<2.0,>=1.3->sceptre) (1.20.67)
Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.5.0,>=0.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from boto3<2.0,>=1.3->sceptre) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from botocore<1.21.0,>=1.20.67->boto3<2.0,>=1.3->sceptre) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from botocore<1.21.0,>=1.20.67->boto3<2.0,>=1.3->sceptre) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Jinja2<3,>=2.8->sceptre) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator<5,>=4.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from networkx<3,>=2.4->sceptre) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from packaging<17.0,>=16.8->sceptre) (2.4.7)
```

Tried this

```
pip uninstall sceptre
pip install sceptre
```

I read some questions here on stackoverflow. People usually resolve this issue with reinstalling the package. In my case, it didn't work. When I run pip list, I can see the version. But I can't run sceptre --version command. Where am I doing wrong?

Thanks!